# Ограничение длины отображаемого текста в <td>

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net, table

Я заполняю `table` данными из базы. Все её содержимое строится и заполняется в цикле в ajax:

```
function ForSearching(args, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/source_pages/SearchForMultilang.ashx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: args,
    }).success(function(data) {
        var table = $("#tablem tbody");
        $("#tablem tbody").empty();
        callback(data);
        $.each(data, function (idx, elem) {
            table.append('<tr data-id=' + elem.Id + '><td id="pname">' + elem.PageName + '</td><td id="lang">' + elem.Lang + '</td><td id="CName">' + elem.ControlName + '</td><td id="CValue">' + elem.ControlValue + '</td><td id="btnRow"><input type="button" onclick=edtClick(this) id="btnedt" value="Edit" /></td></tr>');
        });
    });
}
```

Запрос выполняется, таблица строится. Но в ячейке `<td id="CValue">` значение `elem.ControlValue` иногда бывает очень большим. Как сделать так, чтобы в ячейке отображались не все данные, а только часть, например, 200 символов. При этом, при редактировании строки, когда все ячейки строки трансформируются в `<input type='text'>` со значениями, в input отображалась бы все значение `elem.ControlValue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function reduceControlValue(aValue) {
  if (aValue.length > 200)
    return aValue.substr(0, 200) + "...";
  else
    return aValue;
}

$.each(data, function (idx, elem) {
  table.append('<tr data-id=' + elem.Id + '>' +
    '<td id="pname">' + elem.PageName + '</td>' +
    '<td id="lang">' + elem.Lang + '</td>' + 
    '<td id="CName">' + elem.ControlName + '</td>' +
    '<td id="CValue">' +
      '<span style="display:none" class="fullvalue">' + elem.ControlValue + '</span>' +
      reduceControlValue(elem.ControlValue) + '</td>' + 
    '<td id="btnRow"><input type="button" onclick=edtClick(this) id="btnedt" value="Edit" /></td></tr>'
  );
});
```

и берите значение для редактирования из `$("span.fullvalue").text()` соответствующей строки таблицы.

P.S. Вы создаете элементы с повторяющимися `id`. Это противоречит спецификации html и может привести к проблемам в дальнейшем.